# package android.support.design.widget does not exist import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;

Tags: android-studio

package android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout does not exit ,i got this problem even thought i refactor to android x can someone help me fix this

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM8qI.png)

and this is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'``your text``
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.btl'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.btl"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```